# C# Word - Insert page number object in primary footer section with different first page

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I can't seem to figure out the last line of the following code when adding page numbers to the primary section when different first page is enabled.

Edited to add: I get an Exception Unhandled error "This command is not available" at the last line.

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document myDoc;
myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ReadOnly: false);
myDoc.Activate();

myDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1;

myDoc.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.Text = "First page text";
Object currentPage = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;
myDoc.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Fields.Add(myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, currentPage);
```

Edit: I can get this page number object inserted via the following code if I don't have a different first page but it doesn't work in the above.

```
myDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
Object currentPage = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;
myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, ref currentPage)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the error message, I added it in an edit.